# Using custom php to connect to database blocks wp from accessing galery pictures

Tags: php, database, media-library

I'm using simplepie to get a bunch of rss feeds and post them in a database from which I later show them  on my page. I've added a custom php file with a shortcode to do this.

```
    // Connect to DB
$sDbHost = 'localhost';
$sDbName = 'database_name';
$sDbUser = 'somethin';
$sDbPwd = 'somethin';
$Conn = mysqli_connect($sDbHost, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd);
mysqli_select_db($Conn, $sDbName);

if ($Conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$get_from_table = "SELECT title, link FROM rss_news";
$result = $Conn->query($get_from_table);
mysqli_close($Conn);
```

The database I'm connecting to is a new one I created specifically to do this function, I also created a new user to connect to this db.

This all works, I mange to get the posts into the db and pull them from it to show on the page. The issue is that once this is active it blocks the "add file" option within the classic wordpress editor from accessing the media library.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is there a better  way to connect to the db to avoid blocking other connections?

Comment: Hello! You said you added a custom PHP file and provided the source, but can you be more specific about how this file is called? Is this a file in a plugin? Does it get loaded by WordPress or do you visit the file directly in the browser?

Comment: The file gets added into wordpress via shortcode, I added the php in my theme folder and added the shortcode into my functions.php file.
The file gets loaded by wordpress every time a user opens up the test page I made. Its only opened up when I'm testing and the script opens and closes the db connection so I'm not sure why the media library is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was dumb but it works. I just had to refresh the post article page once and I could access the media library again.

I guess the script would take preference over the media gallery? And then when I refreshed the page it would take preference again and could connect. I'm just guessing here, but if anybody else has this issue this is the simple fix.